# similarity difference of time series data with different time interval

Tags: time-series, data-mining, similarity

Hi I'm currently trying to get score similarity between two time series data.
Metric that are used now is KL-divergence. But I want to know if there are any other metrics. There are many metrics (e.g. [Dynamic time warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping), [Fréchet distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance)). However I can't apply these metrics because my time series data starting time is different. For example, stock_data_1 is starting at monday and stock_data_2 is starting at friday. I want to know if there is metirc that compare two time series data with different starting point and can detect distribution difference which is specific for time series data.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not filter the datasets so that they cover the same range. You could transpose the data but if the day of week is a significant factor, so if the observed behavior is dependent on weekends vs weekdays then you should narrow the result sets to cover a comparable range, the you could transpose the values to make it cover the _same_ range

Comment: Oh it was just exapmle. Actually i dont know the starting points of two data. I just know they are different. But hopefully i have rather large dataset for two distribution.